# How to switch user with pre-configured credentials in SSH Terminal after logging in as standard user

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, putty, su

I am talking about authentication without needing user intervention like specifying password and username in the command file so that user don't need to input anything to switch user. For example: Logging into an SSH session can be something like: putty.exe "IP_ADDRESS" -l User_name -pw Password.

Because my server requires me to log into a standard user first before switching user to the root user, I want to automate this process. I have done the automating of logging into the session but I don't know how to do the same when switching user in the session. How do you include the switch user command with the password parameter in the command file which is executed by a batch file when trying to switch user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What method are you using to switch user accounts?

Comment: Hi, I am using su "username" to switch, they will then prompt me to enter the username's password, I want to automate that by putting the password as a pre-configured parameter sort of thing, like the example shown above, but I haven't found a way to do that in the terminal.

Comment: 1) Are you the admin, and are happy to store the root password in a script 2) Can you use sudo instead of su?  3) Are you certain you always want to be root, rather than escalating to root when absolutely necessary?

Comment: 1) Yes I am an admin, if there's another option to do so, please tell me how to do it, and also how to do it by the script method.
2) Yes, but I would preferably use su.
3) Yes I need to be the root as I am in charge of adding, deleting and modifying user accounts for a propriety system that can only be run in a UNIX environment and only root can do so.

Thank you for your reply Paul.

Comment: The benefit of sudo is that you can take the password in from the command line.  So it would be just a case of `echo Password | sudo -Ss`.  su doesn't let you do this.

Comment: What if I want to grab the password from a command file (.txt), a.k.a through a script? Because our administrators usually use Windows to connect to PUTTY and not usually done in a LINUX environment

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT store the Unix password in a script.
It's much preferable to enable direct root logins.

There is a flag to "Permit root logins" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Optional but recommended: Set PasswordAuthentication to NO 
If you don't do the previous you must make sure the root password is VERY long and VERY nasty.
Use puttygen to create an ssh key for the user
Preferably password the key, use putty-agent to set it up so it only has to be entered once (per day)
Add the public key to /root/.ssh/authorized_logins

You should now be able to login directly as root using the much more secure ssh key to authenticate.

PS: Also install "fail2ban"

PPS: 
The file /etc/sudoers can be configured to allow passwordless sudo; it's done by adding a line like this:

jsmith  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Again, for best security you never do this, but it's much preferable to leaving passwords laying around.